# How do I use Leaflet in Rails 7?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, stimulusjs, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

**What I would like to do:**
I would like to use Leaflet in a Rails 7 app.

**What I did:**
I created my rails app and generated a model (with controller and views) called `map` with only a title. I then added a single map record.

I added leaflet to the app like this:

```
./bin/importmap pin leaflet
```

I added a map `div` with stimulus attributes in `app/views/map/show.html.erb` which now looks like this:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>
<%= render @map %>

<div data-controller="map" data-target="map.placeholder">

<div><%= link_to "Edit this map", edit_map_path(@map) %> | <%= link_to "Back to maps", maps_path %>
<%= button_to "Destroy this map", @map, method: :delete %> </div>
```

I then created `app/javascript/controllers/map_controller.js` looking like this:

```
// map_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "placeholder" ]

  connect(){
    import("leaflet").then( L => {
      this.map = L.map(this.placeholderTarget,{zoomDelta:0.5,zoomSnap:0.5}).setView([ 50.1960, -6.8712 ], 10);

      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(this.map);
    });
  }

  disconnect(){
    this.map.remove()
  }

}
```

**What I got:**
I got random tiles here and there like this:
[image]

I can click on the tiles and move and zoom, and then they flicker, are still messy and even overlay the rails html text like this:
[image]

**What I've tried:**

1. Installing `leaflet-css` with importmap
2. And adding a class attribute with `'leaflet-container'`

but nothing seems to change.

Any suggestions for how I could **get Leaflet working in Rails 7** would be greatly appreciated! (I would really like to get it to work with the default hotwire and stimulus). Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok found the answer myself: Leaflet was missing its css files.

When installing `leaflet-css` with `importmap` (as I mentioned above) the following line is automatically added to `config/importmap.rb` :

```
pin "leaflet-css", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:leaflet-css@0.1.0/dist/leaflet.css.min.js"
```

I then added the following line in the top of the `map_controller.js` file:

```
import "leaflet-css"
```

and added the following to the `div` tag (The style tag is just for testing here. I'll be using tailwind):

```
 class="leaflet-container" style="min-height: 800px;"
```

And then it works as expected:
[image]

Easy and logical in the end. I have a feeling I'm going to like Rails 7!

Comment: how do you import the javascript file for leaflet?

Comment: @Gabriel C - with "./bin/importmap pin leaflet" and then with the import inside the stimulus connect() method as explained in the original question.

Comment: What is `@map` in `<%= render @map %>`? Following your example I get `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

Comment: Looks like I had a maps controller (for standard rails table with maps) and then @map would have been set in the controllers show or rather in the set map called for show and edit probably. You often will not need that at all.

Comment: @MortenGrum I see, I thought it had something to do with the js controller. Completely removing `<%= render @map %>` displays just a blank page. To be certain, is the `div` supposed to look like this? `<div data-controller="map" data-target="map.placeholder" class="leaflet-container" style="min-height: 800px;"></div>`? I have map_controller.js setup like you, but I'm rendering the page from a different named rails controller if that matters somehow.